# series of commands using commons-exec

Tags: apache-commons-exec

I am new to apache commons-exec.

Is there a way I can send a series of commands to a **remote** machine without authenticating each time?

would like to do this order:

```
ssh a@b
command1
command2
```

but apparently commons-exec needs this:

```
ssh a@b \n command1
ssh a@b \n command2
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ssh a@b "command1; command2"
```

this is a common way to execute multiple command on a remote system via ssh from within a script. This should work for your case as well.